# how to wire a hunter bay fan with upper light, lower light with remote control to a led dimmer switch, the led bulbs flicker

Tags: electrical, wiring

I replaced the regular bulbs with led and a single pole switch leds flicker. I replaced the single pole withan led dimmer same problem

Comment: Is there a separate wire for lights vs fan (e.g. black red white coming from the switch)?  Are you dimming just the lights, or the fan also?

Comment: Just what make and model is your fan? Can you post photos of how you have it wired in both boxes?

Comment: If all you did was replace incandescent bulbs with LED bulbs and they began to flicker, what lead you to think the problem was suddenly in the switch? Did you try putting the incandescents back? Please [edit] your post to include focused pics of the switch wiring as well as the make/model of the fan and the LED dimmer switch.

Answer (score 0):

Often times when people run into this, the LEDs are incompatible with dimmers. Check the package when you buy replacements to make sure they are “dimmable” otherwise you will have this issue.

Another issue with the newer fans (read the instruction on wiring) is they state “not to connect to dimmers”.  After contacting the company (Tech Dept), they cited possible fire issues if on either “slide or radial rheostat type” dimmers.    The newer digital are OK if they have the detents or positional 1, 2, 3, 4 selectors for variable speed or brightness.  This is due to the circuit protection built inside the fan housing now (LC -Network) which will bubble up and pop before allowing for a problem.

Comment: Welcome to [diy.se]. I've replaced several ceiling fans in my house over the last 2 or 3 years, all supplied with LED bulbs, but none of them have had any indication that they shouldn't be used with dimmers. I've used 2 different types of dimmers, both with a slider for brightness control, and both are working just fine. I did replace the old radial rheostat dimmers that had been fully functional for the previous 20 years, but were _not_ compatible with LEDs. Is this what you're talking about - older dimmers that simply vary voltage?

Comment: Are you referring to connecting the *fan* to a dimmer? (which is no good, in any case -- you need to use a dedicated *fan speed controller* instead)